# Storing and retrieving global variables from global.asax

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I have an assignment for an ASP.NET project that deals with storing and retrieving global variables from a global.asax file.

My instructor gave me this part for defining the variable:

```
Application.Add("Name", "Andrew");
```

But then after that, he kinda left me hanging. So I was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to point me to the right direction for handling these global variables. Specifically, for calling the variable in a different page of my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To retrieve the value with the following code:

```
string name = Application["Name"]
```

See [How to: Read Values from Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8hhek39.aspx) for more.